# Getting a promiseValue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post, fetch-api

Am new to javascript and I wanted to get the values in the **promiseValue** which is generated after a **POST**. The API am connecting to brings a `json` object as follows :

```
{
    "message": "User logged in successfully",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzE4NTA2ODcsImlhdCI6MTUzMTg0ODg4NywidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ5b3VxQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.oTwcHkW64RS7ooz5_dzrmlvflI4Eg2Y39hGM0D-wZkY"
}
```

But in google chrome am receiving it as a **PromiseValue**, so my target is to get or print the **message** and **token** values out of the **promiseValue**.

Below is the image which shows the **promiseValue** I get:

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDg4P.png)

Below is the code am having so far :

```
fetch('https://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json,text/plain,*/*',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password
        })

    }).then((res) =>{
        if(res.status=='401'){
            console.log(res.status)
            console.log(res.json())
            alert("Sorry please, invalid username or password.");
        }
        else if (res.status='200')
        {
            console.log(res.status)
            console.log(res.json())

        }
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(" my data :   "+data)
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) returns a promise. You need to return it from the first `then` handler to use it in the second `then` handler:

```
fetch(...)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status == '401') {
      ...
    } else if (res.status = '200') {
      ...
    }

    return res.json(); // <-- Add this return call
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(" my data :   " + res);
    console.log(res.token, res.message); // <-- Access the response keys here
  });
```

Comment: how can I get specifically a token and a message from data ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifah -- please look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(...)
 .then(res => {
    if (res.status == '401') {
      throw 'Some error message'; // <-- Add this throw exeption
      ...
    } else if (res.status = '200') {
      ...
    }

   return res.json(); // <-- Add this return call 
   })
   .then(res => {
      console.log(" my data :   " + res);
      console.log(res.token, res.message); // <-- Access the response keys here
   })
   .catch(e => console.error(e)) // <-- Catch your errors here
```